# Meteor.js voice chat

Tags: meteor

Is there a Meteor extension or something that would enable voice chat between users? (I don't have a problem with it being routed through the server first, but I don't know if this is necessary)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve both video and chat using meteor-webrtc. Check out https://github.com/foxdog-studios/meteor-webrtc .

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source solution (MIT license) you can deploy without writing a single line of code:

https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat